# How to animate chart with multiple y axis (python)

Tags: python, plot, plotly, yaxis, plotly-express

I am trying to make animated plot (currently using plotly.express but open to any other solutions) with secondary y axis. I have read different threads about how to animate a bar chart with multiple groups ([Plotly: How to animate a bar chart with multiple groups using plotly express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780291/plotly-how-to-animate-a-bar-chart-with-multiple-groups-using-plotly-express)) and make second axis on plotly-express ([Plotly: How to plot on secondary y-Axis with plotly express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853539/plotly-how-to-plot-on-secondary-y-axis-with-plotly-express)), however I havent found any answer on how to make animated plot with secondary y axis.

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.read_csv("plotly_animation_stackoverflow.csv")
px.bar(data_frame=df,x="date",y=["A","B","C"],animation_frame="lag",barmode="group")
```

and I cannot see the bar chart for column C because of scale issue

[image]

There is also an issue with plotly-express as my data frame expand with additional lags. I can easily do this in Tableau, however I am trying to keep this open source. Is there another way that I can pass a function to a plot that it applies additional lags as I move the slide bar?

here is the data

```
date,A,B,C,lag
8/22/2016,54987,36488,0.3389,0
8/23/2016,91957,73793,0.3389,0
8/24/2016,91957,73793,0.3357,0
8/25/2016,91957,73793,0.3291,0
8/26/2016,91957,73793,0.3295,0
8/29/2016,91957,73793,0.3281,0
8/30/2016,107657,82877,0.3273,0
8/31/2016,107657,82877,0.3247,0
9/1/2016,107657,82877,0.322,0
9/2/2016,107657,82877,0.3266,0
8/22/2016,54987,36488,NA,1
8/23/2016,91957,73793,0.3389,1
8/24/2016,91957,73793,0.3389,1
8/25/2016,91957,73793,0.3357,1
8/26/2016,91957,73793,0.3291,1
8/29/2016,91957,73793,0.3295,1
8/30/2016,107657,82877,0.3281,1
8/31/2016,107657,82877,0.3273,1
9/1/2016,107657,82877,0.3247,1
9/2/2016,107657,82877,0.322,1
9/3/2016,,,0.3266,1
8/22/2016,54987,36488,,2
8/23/2016,91957,73793,,2
8/24/2016,91957,73793,0.3389,2
8/25/2016,91957,73793,0.3389,2
8/26/2016,91957,73793,0.3357,2
8/29/2016,91957,73793,0.3291,2
8/30/2016,107657,82877,0.3295,2
8/31/2016,107657,82877,0.3281,2
9/1/2016,107657,82877,0.3273,2
9/2/2016,107657,82877,0.3247,2
9/3/2016,,,0.322,2
9/4/2016,,,0.3266,2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- after building the figure, update required traces to use secondary y-axis.  This needs to include traces within frames as well as traces within figure
- configure secondary y-axis

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import io

data = """date,A,B,C,lag
8/22/2016,54987,36488,0.3389,0
8/23/2016,91957,73793,0.3389,0
8/24/2016,91957,73793,0.3357,0
8/25/2016,91957,73793,0.3291,0
8/26/2016,91957,73793,0.3295,0
8/29/2016,91957,73793,0.3281,0
8/30/2016,107657,82877,0.3273,0
8/31/2016,107657,82877,0.3247,0
9/1/2016,107657,82877,0.322,0
9/2/2016,107657,82877,0.3266,0
8/22/2016,54987,36488,NA,1
8/23/2016,91957,73793,0.3389,1
8/24/2016,91957,73793,0.3389,1
8/25/2016,91957,73793,0.3357,1
8/26/2016,91957,73793,0.3291,1
8/29/2016,91957,73793,0.3295,1
8/30/2016,107657,82877,0.3281,1
8/31/2016,107657,82877,0.3273,1
9/1/2016,107657,82877,0.3247,1
9/2/2016,107657,82877,0.322,1
9/3/2016,,,0.3266,1
8/22/2016,54987,36488,,2
8/23/2016,91957,73793,,2
8/24/2016,91957,73793,0.3389,2
8/25/2016,91957,73793,0.3389,2
8/26/2016,91957,73793,0.3357,2
8/29/2016,91957,73793,0.3291,2
8/30/2016,107657,82877,0.3295,2
8/31/2016,107657,82877,0.3281,2
9/1/2016,107657,82877,0.3273,2
9/2/2016,107657,82877,0.3247,2
9/3/2016,,,0.322,2
9/4/2016,,,0.3266,2"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))
fig = px.bar(data_frame=df,x="date",y=["A","B","C"],animation_frame="lag",barmode="group")

# update approprate traces to use secondary yaxis
for t in fig.data:
    if t.name=="C": t.update(yaxis="y2")
for f in fig.frames:
    for t in f.data:
        if t.name=="C": t.update(yaxis="y2")

# configure yaxis2 and give it some space
fig.update_layout(yaxis2={"overlaying":"y", "side":"right"}, xaxis={"domain":[0,.98]})
```

[image]